# How to show "Estimated Balance Changes" (transaction may fail to confirm) for anchor program

Tags: anchor, transactions, phantom

I am trying to send a transaction that consists of:

1. SOL transfer
2. Anchor Program instruction

[image]

Although, for the "Estimated Balance Changes" part of Phantom Wallet, it will always say "Transaction may fail to confirm"

[image]

Is there any way to not display "Transaction may fail to confirm"?

By the way, I have skipPreflight set to false so that transaction simulations are allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phantom simulates transactions via Solana web3js's [simulateTransation](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#simulateTransaction) method. If your transaction is able to be simulated via this method, but consistently fails simulation within Phantom, please double check that your Phantom wallet is set to the same network you intend to simulate on.